# Eclipse PDT, XDebug and WAMP. Eclipse not stopping at breakpoint

Tags: php, eclipse, wamp, xdebug

I have the following environment.

OS: Win 7 64 Bit
WAMP Server 2.2
PHP: 5.3.8
Apache: Apache2.2.21
Eclipse: Version: 3.7.1
PDT: 3.0
Xdebug: php_xdebug-2.1.3-5.3-vc9-x86_64.dll

XDebug is configured and showing up in phpinfo.
I see Xdebug session is starting and ending in the browser.

But for some reason, eclipse is not stopping at any breakpoints. I even try to set "Break at first line". But nothing is working.

Tried several suggestions by Forums. Nothing is working.

Not sure if I am missing something or my set is weird?

Please let me know your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first ,you run the `phpinfo();`
get your info,and Ctrl+A,copy all the information,then put all the words into this textarea.[http://xdebug.org/find-binary][1],and the xdebug will tell you the xdebug's version and config put the end of your php.ini file.

check the eclipse menu "stop at first line",make sure now you useing the xdebug,not the zenddebug in your eclipse.

good luck

Comment: Thanks, @welsonla. I tried that already. It shows everything good. As I mentioned, XDEBUG is running fine. I think the breakpoints are working in FF as well. But not from Eclipse.

Comment: I don't know what I did. But I got it working. Changed several things. But not sure which worked. :-)

Answer (score 2):

One of the things that helped me solve this issue was adding the following line to the relevant php.ini file

```
xdebug.remote_enable=1
```

Answer (score 1):

see match the versions of your PHP & Eclipse....sometimes it is also help to solve the problem.

my breakpoint is not stopping so that I checked the eclipse and PHP & xdebug verson and get my problem solved.

Also check Eclipse "Preference-->PHP-->PHP Interpretor" and version of PHP.